# How to test methods and callback using Mocha, Chai, & Enzyme in React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, chai, enzyme

I have to write unit test cases for a `PlayerList` container and `Player` component. Writing test cases for branches and props is OK, but how do I test the component's methods and the logic inside them. My code coverage is incomplete because the methods are not tested.

**Scenario:**

Parent component passes a reference to its method `onSelect` as a callback to child component. The method is defined in `PlayerList` component, but `Player` is generating the onClick event that calls it.

**Parent Component/Container:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {selectTab} from '../actions/index';
import Player from './Player';

class PlayerList extends Component {    
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    onSelect(i) {
        if (!i) {
            this.props.selectPlayer(1);
        }
        else {
            this.props.selectPlayer(i);
        }
    }

    createListItems(){      
        return this.props.playerList.map((item, i)=>{
            return (                
                    <Player key={i} tab={item} onSelect={() => this.onSelect(item.id)} />
                )
        });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className="col-md-12">
                <ul className="nav nav-tabs">                   
                    {this.createListItems()}
                </ul>   
            </div>
        )   
    }   
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return {
    playerList: state.playerList 
  }
}
function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return bindActionCreators({selectPlayer: selectPlayer}, dispatch);
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(PlayerList);
```

**Child Component:**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    class Player extends Component {    
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
        }

        render() {
            return(
                <li className={this.props.player.selected?'active':''}>
                    <a href="#"  onClick={() => this.props.onSelect(this.props.player.id)}>
                       <img src={this.props.player.imgUrl}     className="thumbnail"/>
                        {this.props.player.name}
                    </a>
                </li>
            )   
        }   
    }
    export default Player;
```

Answer (score 10):

### Use enzyme's `.instance()` method to access component methods

There are a couple of prerequisites of course.

1. You have to render the component once first, using enzyme's [`shallow`](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html) or [`mount`](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/mount.html) functions depending on whether you need to *[and/or how you prefer to]* [simulate](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/simulate.html) events on nested children. This also gives you an enzyme wrapper from which you'll access the component instance and its methods.
2. You'll need to wrap [sinon test spies](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#spies) around those instance methods and re-render using [`.update`](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/update.html) to get a version of the wrapper with spies on which you can assert.

**Example:**

```js
// Import requisite modules
import React from 'react';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import PlayerList from './PlayerList';

// Describe what you'll be testing
describe('PlayerList component', () => {
  // Mock player list
  const playerList = [
    {
      id    : 1,
      imgUrl: 'http://placehold.it/100?text=P1',
      name  : 'Player One'
    }
  ];

  // Nested describe just for our instance methods
  describe('Instance methods', () => {
    // Stub the selectPlayer method.
    const selectPlayer = sinon.stub();
    // Full DOM render including nested Player component
    const wrapper = mount(
      <PlayerList playerList={ playerList } selectPlayer={ selectPlayer } />
    );
    // Get the component instance
    const instance = wrapper.instance();

    // Wrap the instance methods with spies
    instance.createListItems = sinon.spy(instance.createListItems);
    instance.onSelect        = sinon.spy(instance.onSelect);

    // Re-render component. Now with spies!
    wrapper.update();

    it('should call createListItems on render', () => {
      expect(instance.createListItems).to.have.been.calledOnce;
    });

    it('should call onSelect on child link click', () => {
      expect(instance.onSelect).to.not.have.been.called;
      wrapper.find('li > a').at(0).simulate('click');
      expect(instance.onSelect).to.have.been.calledOnce;
      expect(instance.onSelect).to.have.been.calledWith(playerList[0].id);
    });
  });
});
```

**Notes:**

- When using the above code for `PlayerList` and `Player`, I discovered that you are not assigning a prop called `player` to `Player`; instead you are assigning `item={ item }`. To get this working locally, I changed it to `<Player player={ item } … />`.
- In `onSelect` you are checking whether the received `i` argument is falsey and then calling `selectPlayer(1)`. I didn't include a test case for this in the above example because the logic concerns me for a couple of reasons:

  1. I wonder if `i` could ever be `0`? If so, it will always evaluate as falsey and get passed into that block.
  2. Because `Player` calls `onSelect(this.props.player.id)`, I wonder if `this.props.player.id` would ever be `undefined`? If so, I wonder why you would have an item in `props.playerList` with no `id` property.

But if you wanted to test that logic as it is now, it would look something like this…

**Example testing logic in `onSelect`:**

```js
describe('PlayerList component', () => {
  …
  // Mock player list should contain an item with `id: 0`
  // …and another item with no `id` property.
  const playerList = [
    …, // index 0 (Player 1)
    {  // index 1
      id    : 0,
      imgUrl: 'http://placehold.it/100?text=P0',
      name  : 'Player Zero'
    },
    {  // index 2
      imgUrl: 'http://placehold.it/100?text=P',
      name  : 'Player ?'
    }
  ];
  describe('Instance methods', { … });
  describe('selectPlayer', () => {
    const selectPlayer = sinon.stub();
    const wrapper = mount(
      <PlayerList playerList={ playerList } selectPlayer={ selectPlayer } />
    );
    const instance = wrapper.instance();

    // There is no need to simulate clicks or wrap spies on instance methods
    // …to test the call to selectPlayer. Just call the method directly.
    it('should call props.selectPlayer with `id` if `id` is truthy', () => {
      instance.onSelect(playerList[0].id); // id: 1
      expect(selectPlayer).to.have.been.calledOnce;
      expect(selectPlayer).to.have.been.calledWith(playerList[0].id);
    });

    it('should call props.selectPlayer(1) if `id` is 0', () => {
      instance.onSelect(playerList[1].id); // id: 0
      expect(selectPlayer).to.have.been.calledTwice;
      expect(selectPlayer).to.have.been.calledWith(1);
    });

    it('should call props.selectPlayer(1) if `id` is undefined', () => {
      instance.onSelect(playerList[2].id); // undefined
      expect(selectPlayer).to.have.been.calledThrice;
      expect(selectPlayer).to.have.been.calledWith(1);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use enzyme's `simulate` function to test callbacks. You can provide callback functions as spy functions from sinon and verify that it has been called expected times with expected arguments.
You can read more on this here:
https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/simulate.md

Here is the unit tests for Player and PlayerList components simulating the callback functions. You need the separate PlayerList component as PlayerList and PlayerListContainer(indicating that the component connected to redux). After doing this, you can easily test your PlayerList component.

PlayerListTest.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import PlayerList from 'components/PlayerList';
import Player from 'components/Player';

describe('PlayerList test', () => {
  const playerList = [
    {
      id: '1',
      imgUrl: 'testimageurl',
      name: 'testplayer1'
    },
    {
      id: '23423',
      imgUrl: 'http://testimageurl2',
      name: 'testplayer2'
    },
    {
      id: '123124123',
      imgUrl: 'http://testimageurl23',
      name: 'testplayer142'
    }
  ];

  it('calls callback function with item id when player is selected', () => {
    const mockSelectPlayer = sinon.spy();
    const wrapper = shallow(<PlayerList playerList={playerList} selectPlayer={mockSelectPlayer} />);

    const playerWrapper = wrapper.find(Player);
    playerWrapper.at(0).simulate('select');

    expect(mockSelectPlayer.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
    expect(mockSelectPlayer.calledWith(playerList[0].id)).to.be.ok;
  });


});
```

PlayerTest.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import Player from 'components/Player.jsx';

describe('Player test', () => {
  const player = {
    id: '1234',
    imgUrl: 'http://testimageurl',
    name: 'testplayer'
  };

  it('calls callback function when the .player-container element clicked', () => {
    const mockOnSelect = sinon.spy();
    const wrapper = shallow(<Player player={player} onSelect={mockOnSelect} />);

    wrapper.find('.player-container').simulate('click');

    expect(mockOnSelect.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
  });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't show the scenario described by the OP with nested components triggering class methods.

Comment: You can use enzyme's `mount` method for complete rendering of your component. This way you can call nested component's callback function using `simulate` of enzyme.

Comment: Can you include an example unit test showing how a method of a parent component can be spied on and called by a simulated click?

Comment: That's a good example of unit testing callback functions passed as props, but you're not showing "how to test [the] methods and logic inside the methods" where "[the] Method is defined in Parent component". OP wants to test `PlayerList.onSelect`.

Comment: You can  test that by giving `undefined` to a playerId and `simulate` `select` event again. In that case callback function should have been called with `1`. You do not have to directly call every method on your component to test your component.

Comment: That is true for `onSelect` which calls 'selectPlayer`. But often you want to test a method that doesn't have easily observable side effects. In which case you want to see that it was directly called with the expected arguments. But you're right that testing the end result is sometimes sufficient.