# How can I test a method from third party library?

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, sinon, chai, enzyme

I am using a 3rd party library for logging some events, setup in my component:

In component `componentDidMount`:

```
this.evenStream = new thirdPartyLib();
this.evenStream.setArgs(args);
this.evenStream.addQueue('the'); // should be 'the-spell' for misspell page
const event1 = new Event1();
const event2 = new Event2();
this.evenStream.addQueue(event1); // adds events in sequence in queue
this.evenStream.addQueue(event2); // adds events in sequence  in queue
this.evenStream.reportEvents(); // reports events previously added to queue, once reported the queue is cleared
```

In test:

```
this.wrapper = mount(<component  />); // looks good
this.evenStreamInstance = this.wrapper.instance().evenStream; //returns properties of evenStream
this.eventStub = sinon.stub(this.evenStreamInstance, 'reportEvents');
expect(this.wrapper).to.be.ok; // looks good
expect(this.evenStreamInstance).to.exist; // looks good
expect(this.eventStub).to.have.been.called; // returns error

AssertionError: expected reportEvents to have been called at least once, but it was never called
```

I am sure the events are being logged correctly, I've checked the stream and all looks good, am not sure how to test it. Ideally I would like to test what all events are added to `addQueue` and then get reported but I am not able to capture that information.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**Update** 
I tried again as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39396357/how-to-test-methods-and-callback-using-mocha-chai-enzyme-in-react-redux?rq=1) with stub, but still getting same error

```
const eventStub = sinon.stub(new thirdPartyLib());
this.wrapper = mount(<component evenStream={eventStub} />); //looks good
this.evenStreamInstance = this.wrapper.instance().evenStream; //returns properties of evenStream
this.evenStreamInstance.reportEvents = sinon.spy(this.evenStreamInstance.reportEvents);

expect(this.wrapper).to.be.ok; // looks good
expect(this.evenStreamInstance).to.exist; //looks good
this.wrapper.update();
expect(this.evenStreamInstance.reportEvents).to.have.been.calledOnce; // gives error

AssertionError: expected reportEvents to have been called exactly once, but it was called 0 times
```

Comment: use `sinon.stub(thirdPartyLib.prototype)`

Comment: So I updated `const eventStub` to be `sinon.stub(new thirdPartyLib().prototype);`  but that's returning `undefined` for `const eventStub`

Comment: It's not `new thirdPartyLib().prototype` it's just `thirdPartyLib.prototype`

Comment: even with `thirdPartyLib.prototype` am still getting the same error

Comment: Call the `this.wrapper.instance().componentDidMount()` explicitly after setting the `sinon.spy` and modify `sinon.spy` to `this.evenStreamInstance.reportEvents = sinon.spy()` @user988544 the problem is you are setting the spy after the component is mounted and so the spy doesn't get called.

Comment: Would `this.wrapper.update()` be equivalent of `this.wrapper.instance().componentDidMount()` ? I am sorry am new to this, or is there any other way to explicitly call `componentDidMount()` ?

Comment: That wouldn't be equivalent. You would have explicitly call it using `this.wrapper.instance().componentDidMount()`